# Highcharts not Drawing point on setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I have data being put on an api every 30 seconds on a backend. On the frontend I am using highcharts to visualize the data and a setInterval setup to retrieve the new data every 30 seconds. My problem is that on that setInterval, the line graph disappears or does not draw to the next new dot. Does anyone now why this is?

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b8tf281n/3/

code:

```
chart1 = {
    yAxisMin: 40,
    yAxisMax: 100
};
// empty objects for our data and to create chart
seriesData = [];
BPM = [];
time1 = [];

// console.log(chart1.data.series);

$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });



        var url = 'http://msbandhealth.azurewebsites.net/odata/PulsesAPI/';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            context: seriesData,
            success: function (data) {



                // structure our data 
                for (var i = 0; i < data.value.length; i++) {
                    bpm = data.value[i].BPM;
                    time = data.value[i].Time;
                    BPM.push({
                        x: moment(time),
                        y: bpm
                    });
                    // console.log(BPM);
                    time1.push(time);
                }
                console.log((new Date).getTime());
                console.log(moment(time, "DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm:ss"));
                console.log(BPM);
                console.log(BPM[BPM.length - 1]);
                // console.log(seriesData);

                // set our data series and create new chart
                chart1.data.series[0].data = BPM;

                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chart1.data);
                $('#container').css({
                    height: '400px'
                });


                // console.log(sortedBPM);


                // console.log(time1);

            }

        });




        // give highcharts something to render to
        var container = document.getElementById("container");

        chart1.data = {

            chart: {
                renderTo: container,
                type: 'spline',
                animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                marginRight: 10,
                events: {
                    load: function () {
                        setInterval(function () {

                            // find last data points
                            var test = BPM[BPM.length - 1];
                            var x = (new Date).getTime(),
                                y = test.y;
                            console.log(x);

                            shift = chart.series[0].data.length < 30;
                            chart.series[0].addPoint([x, y], true, true);




                        },
                        30000);
                    }
                }

            },
            title: {
                text: 'Microsoft Band: Real Time Pulse Analysis'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150,
                dateTimeLabelFormats: {


                },
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: chart1.yAxisMin,
                max: chart1.yAxisMax,
                title: {
                    text: 'Heart Rate'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Beats Per Minute',
                data: []
            }]


        };

    });
});
```

Comment: I have also tried changing my interval to longer than 30seconds with the same result

Comment: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts

Comment: I've been all over their api, particularly the addPoint section. Thank you though.

Comment: hmmmm create a new function to pause / stop animation on setInterval until ready for next

Answer (score 0):

Your **`test.y`** is the problem. It returns **undefined** after one interval. Somehow **`BPM`** is changing in it's structure - changing each object from {x,y} to [0,1] - therefore I used:

```
 y = (test.y !== undefined)? test.y : test[1];
```

to either get the previous structure or the new. I also set the interval to 3 seconds for you to see the difference easier. Here's the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/b8tf281n/6/).

Comment: What if `test.y = 0`? I think you should check if `test.y` is undefined.

Comment: @RaeenHashemi your answer made me realize something...I am pretty sure BPM is only updated once in the ajax call at the load. after that it is not updated which is probably why it comes back undefined or with the same point when i reference the last index in the area. Your demo looks great. The problem is, the api will only update every 30 seconds if the device that sends the data is on. At this point the device is not on and your demo still updates. Do you follow? So i wonder if I should put another ajax call in the set interval function? will that kill the browser? Thank you

Comment: yes, BPM is updated once since the ajax call, but the **`addPoint`** function updates BPM in every interval somehow which I don't know. About the 30seconds part I don't follow actually, but putting an ajax call every 30 seconds wouldn't be that bad.